# Prove or disprove that the following group makes a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So, this question has me completely stumped. I'm supposed to either prove or disprove that the following group makes a vector space. Here are the conditions I must prove:

V$\mathbb{=F=C}$ with regular addition of $\mathbb{C}$ and with the following scalar multiplication:
∀α ∈ F, v ∈ V | α$\boxdot$v = (Reα)v

Comment: Calling this a group is confusing. _Without_ the multiplication it is indeed an additive group, but that is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Scalar multiplication must be compatible with the multiplication rule in the field.  Thus we require that $$a(b\vec v)=(ab)\vec v$$

For all $a,b\in \mathbb F$.

Alas, this fails in your example.  Take, say, $a=b=i$.

Comment: Just clarifying: why would'nt we have Re(a)(Re(b)v)=0=Re(a)Re(b)v? Is it that it would actually be Re(a)(Re(b)v)=0, Re(ab)v=-1v?

Comment: If $a,b\in \mathbb R$ then the compatibility holds.  However if we take $a=b=i$ and $\vec v$ any non-zero vector, we get that $i\boxdot \vec v=\vec 0$ so the left hand is $\vec 0$.  The right hand, however, is $-\vec v$

Comment: Ok. so basically,:  (a*b)⊡$\vec v$=Re(a)*Re(b)*$\vec v$?

Comment: What?  Why would that be? $(a* b)\boxdot \vec v=Re(a* b)\vec v$.  I mean, it's your definition.

Comment: All I am doing is following your definition.  If $b=i$ then $b\boxdot \vec v=i\boxdot \vec v = Re(i)\vec v =\vec 0$.  And so on.

Comment: I'm sorry but doesn't Re(i∗i)=-1? The proof with just b=i makes sense to me, but not with the a.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58347/discussion-between-user3250068-and-lulu).